# client validation on jquery 2.1.1

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am using MVC5 and am trying to get client validation to trigger rather than doing server trip.The validation works server side but I can't get the client side to trigger using jquery 2.1.1

I am using bundles to register the scripts. In the client source the scripts seem  to be referenced correctly.

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

In the web.config I have enabled clientside and unobtrusive

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

One of the inputs that needs validating seems to be picking up the data annotations from the model so I don't think that's the issue

```
<input class="input-validation-error form-control" data-val="true"
 data-val-number="The field UpdateValue must be a number."
 data-val-range="Please enter a number between 1 and 28"
 data-val-range-max="28" data-val-range-min="1"
 data-val-required="An update value is required" id="tbUpdateValue"
 name="UpdateValue" type="text" value="0" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true">`
```

The only way I can get the client side to trigger is it to add a reference to an older version of jQuery. I added this at the top of my view

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

Any idea on how I can get this to work with 2.1.1 or am doing something stupid?

Comment: oh and when I say it doesn't trigger. I mean it goes to the controller and the server deals with the validation

Comment: What is the browser you are checking ?, Jquery 2.x doesn't support IE 6, 7, or 8.

Comment: I am using Chrome 35.0.1916.153

Comment: Did you update the jquery via nuget? When you update Jquery did you update the jquery.validate and jquery.validate.unobtrusive accordingly ?

Comment: Yeah I've updated them via nuget - Jquery unobtrusive is v3.2.0 and valdation is v1.13.0

Comment: [Read the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org).  jQuery Validate has not been tested with jQuery version 2, so maybe with `unobtrusive`, it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a jQuery conflict. Try using the noConflict in jQuery like this:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem. Looks like jQuery validate does not work with jQuery 2.1.1

Maybe you should try

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation/